# Miscalculation of array size inside a function

Tags: c, arrays

The following C program:

```
int doStuff(int afm[]);

int main(){
    int afm1[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; //size=9

    int afmLength = sizeof(afm1)/sizeof(int);
    printf("main: Length Of Array=%d\n", afmLength);  //9 OK

    int k = doStuff(afm1);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
}

int doStuff(int afm[]){
    int afmLength = sizeof(afm)/sizeof(int);    
    printf("doStuff: Length Of Array=%d\n", afmLength);  //1 WRONG

    return 1;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
main: Length Of Array=9
doStuff: Length Of Array=1
```

Why is the array size calculated correctly in main, but is wrong inside the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in `main` you have an array and in the function you have a pointer to that array.

```
int doStuff(int afm[])
```

is equivalent to

```
int doStuff(int *afm)
```

Comment: Thanks David. What should i write instead?

Comment: Argote's answer tells you. The function `doStuff` has no information about the length of the array. You would need to pass that information into the function along with the pointer to the array.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to David Heffernan's answer (which is correct), you should have another parameter which would be the array length passed onto your `doStuff` method.

Comment: +1 I change "size" to "length" because it is more normal to work with lengths than sizes (I'm sure that's what you meant anyway).

Answer (score 0):

From the C language standard (draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

Memorize that paragraph, since one of the biggest sources of heartburn in C programming is how C treats array expressions.

When you call `doStuff(afm1);`, the expression `afm1` is implicitly converted from type "9-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the expression's value is the same as `&afm1[0]`.  So what `doStuff` receives is a pointer value, not an array.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are both interpreted as `T *a`:

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

Since `doStuff` receives a *pointer* value and not an array, the `sizeof` trick doesn't work.  In general, you have to explicitly tell a function how large of an array you're passing to it; you can't determine that from the pointer value itself.

So, when you call `doStuff` from `main`, you'll need to do something like

```
doStuff(afm1, sizeof afm1/sizeof *afm1);
...
int doStuff(int *afm, size_t afmsize)
{
  ...
}
```